# Extjs calling class of an object

Tags: javascript, extjs

Example: In JQuery we call

```
var par = $('#container');
console.log($('.subcontainer', par).length);
```

In EXTJS how do we do that?

```
var par = Ext.get('container'); // Is the prepare parent object.
```

But `Ext.select('.subcontainer', par).length` isn't working

Help me out in calling a class from an object using EXTJS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select` returns a collection class: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.dom.CompositeElementLite

You want to call the `getCount` method.

A better way to call it would be:

`var items = Ext.get('container').select('.subcontainer');`